# Reduce a grid array [][] into a string

Tags: javascript, array

I have a class with a property of `grid[][]` and each value is either true or false. I need to convert this to a string with letters o and b in place of the boolean.

First way, simple for loops over the array and return the string:

```
 get rle() {
     let result = "";
     for(let y = 0; y < this.grid.length; y++) {
         for(let x =0; x < this.grid[y].length; x++) {
             result += ( (this.grid[y][x]) ?  "o" : "b" );
         }
     }
     return result;
}
```

Or a more JS style solution?

```
get rle() {
    return this.grid.reduce( (total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr) => {
        return total + arr[currentIndex].reduce( (total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr) => {
            return total + ( (arr[currentIndex]) ?  "o" : "b" );
        }, "");
    }, "");
 }
```

Is this a good JS style solution, and what in your opinion is better? I prefer the first because anyone can instantly understand it. The JS solution makes me frown with 3 nested returns, looks odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a few points of the code you wrote. If you have an array of values, you can [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the values together to efficiently create a string. This would eliminate the need for at least one of the `reduce` calls. Second, in a reduce call, the value of the second callback parameter (`currentValue` in your code) is the value of the array parameter at the index parameter (`arr[currentIndex]` in your code). Combining that with Javascript's capability to ignore excess function parameters, your `reduce` calls should take only two parameters, and use the `currentValue` in place of the `arr[currentIndex]`.

You should also avoid using the same variable names in the same scope. Having two sets of `total`, `currentValue`, `currentIndex`, and `arr` could get confusing quickly, and lead to strange bugs.

Now, for the one-liner:

```
return this.grid.flat().map((el) => el ? "o" : "b").join("");
```

See [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and the aforementioned `Array#join`. Of these, `Array#flat` is the newest and possibly unsupported method. It can be easily polyfilled or replaced. The MDN page shows some clever replacements like `arr.reduce((all, row) => all.concat(row), [])` and `[].concat(...arr)`.

Comment: Yes, And this method will work faster too...

Comment: That's the one liner I was looking for. Back to the arrays manual for me.. thanks cbojar.